# video not playing in popup box in lightbox

Tags: video, iframe, gallery, lightbox

I have 18 images lightbox gallery, Popup image is working fine after click on particular image but I have embeded video in some images click to popup but after popup video is not appearing or working, please help.

```html
<div><img src="images/xyz.jpg" alt="xyz"/><a href="#lightbox-1"></a></div>

<div class="lightbox" id="lightbox-1">
  <div class="content"><a href="https://www.youtube.com" class="wplightbox" data-width=960 data-height=540 data-autoopen="true" data-autoopendelay=1000 data-autoclose="true" data-mutevideo="true"></a><a class="close" href="#gallery"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```